# Wait for method to complete before calling it

Tags: angular

I  have an issue whereby a method that I am calling does not provide a value in time. Here is my code.

```
  getStoredData(): StorageModel {
    const data =  JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(`oidc.user:${environment.accessTokenApiUrl}:${environment.clientId}`));
    return data;
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
    if (this._storeService.getStoredData()) {
      if (
        this._storeService.getStoredData().id_token &&
        this._storeService.getStoredData().profile.role
      ) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }



  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.authService.isAuthenticated()){
      //do something
    } else {
      //do something else
    }
  }
```

The `isAuthenticated` returns null but gets a value after a couple of seconds. However because it is called onInit, it calls the method and there is no value at that time.

How can I await the value to be returned?

Comment: Can you post your auth service code. It's hard to guess at what's going on, and it's crucial to understanding your problem.

Comment: Does authService.isAuthenticated() makes an ajax request in background?

Comment: @AnkushJain it just calls getStoredData which returns values from sessionStorage

Comment: I would suggest better to call this method In `ngAfterViewInit` hook instead of `ngOnInit`, can you try it once and let me know, or either try to return a promise from the service and proceed accordingly.

Comment: @KurtHamilton the isAuthenticated method exists in auth service as a stand alone method(not in constructor)

Comment: @skydev Yes, I assumed that would be the case. It would be nice to see that code, as that's where the problem lies.

Comment: How you are confident that it gets a value after a couple of seconds? Any proof?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **async** and **await** feature of javascript. 
 Whenever you mention a task as an async then the programm execution on the main thread will be halted untill the task gets completed.

```
async getStoredData(): StorageModel {
  const dataObj = await sessionStorage.getItem(`oidc.user:${environment.accessTokenApiUrl}:${environment.clientId}`);
  const data =  JSON.parse(dataObj);
  return data;
}
```

You might have to do the same for your isAuthenticated method also.